List probing paths in current assembly in runtime where references are going to be searched for
I would like to list all the paths where the Runtime is going to search for the assemblies that are needed to be loaded. The idea is to explicit all the probes that will be tried, according to How the runtime locates assemblies, maybe in the right order they are tried.
I have seen that in .Net Core it exists an AssemblyLoadContext.Default property that maybe could give me that info, but I want to get it in .NET Framework 4.8.
Finally, I don't know if it is Application-specific or Assembly-specific, but I think it would be of use in any case although the Assembly-specific case seems more interesting.
--EDIT--
I just found that I can use the fuslogvw app included in Visual Studio. When an assembly load fails it lists all the attempted paths. Unfortunately, when it succedes, it only shows the paths attempted until the successfull path is found.

What about unmanaged libraries ? (tlrd).

@Sinatr, I was looking for something simplier (if it exists), that reflects the final paths for searching for managed libs that includes all the Probings and Codebase instances along with other default search paths, without using 3rd party apps or libraries (just c# or even VS tools)
